# FullCalendar in Vue Class Component

Tags: vuejs2, fullcalendar, vue-class-components

I would like to use [FullCalendar vue](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue) within a [vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) but can't make it working.

Following [FullCalendar documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue), I'm able to use it with the provided sample.
Once translated to a [vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component), I'm struggling.
Mainly declaring the FullCalendar component doesn't work.

```js
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import { PluginDef } from '@fullcalendar/core';

@Component({
  components: {
    FullCalendar
  }
})
export default class Dashboard extends Vue {

  calendarPlugins: PluginDef[] = [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin];
[...]
```

This gives me the following error:

```
ERROR in xxx\dashboard.component.ts
[tsl] ERROR in xxx\dashboard.component.ts(9,3)
      TS2345: Argument of type '{ components: { FullCalendar: { props: { header: {}; footer: {}; customButtons: {}; buttonIcons: {}; themeSystem: {}; bootstrapFontAwesome: {}; firstDay: {}; dir: {}; weekends: {}; hiddenDays: {}; fixedWeekCount: {}; ... 130 more ...; resourceRender: {}; }; ... 6 more ...; methods: { ...; }; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'VueClass<Vue>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'components' does not exist in type 'VueClass<Vue>'. Did you mean to write 'component'?
```